# Reading out a 16bit timer on an 8bit system without a latch for the high/low byte

Tags: timer, microcontroller, c99

I have a timer that I use on a regular basis to gather performance values.
Now, I've seen that sometimes, I get a value that is lower than the one sampled before.

I found to trace this behaviour back to the fact, that I do:
1) Read the lower byte
2) Read the upper byte

> value = upper<<8 + lower

But what happens sometimes is:
1) Read the lower byte
*2) Overflow of lower byte occurs, lower = 0, higher++*
3) Read the upper byte *(Is too high now!)*

> value = (upper<<8) + lower + *[a value smaller 255]*

If I switch the order:
1) Read the upper byte
*2) Overflow of lower byte occurs, lower = 0, higher++*
3) Read the lower byte *(Is too low now!)*

> value = (upper<<8) + lower - *[a value smaller 255]*

So, I both these cases, I get a deviation from my real value.

---

**Is there any better solution to this than the ones presented below?**
**Or is there even established solution?**

---

What I did now is this:

```
/* Sample as long as it takes to not hit an overflow 
   between sampling the lower and the upper byte */

do {
    upper = CounterH;
    lower = CounterL;
} while (upper != CounterH);
```

But I'm afraid, as this keeps potential for a deadlock!!
(If the timer counts fast enough)

---

I was also considering this:

```
__DI();

upper =  CounterH;
lower =  CounterL;
value1 = upper<<8 + lower;

upper =  CounterH;
lower =  CounterL;
value2 = upper<<8 + lower;

value = max(value1, value2);

__EI();
```

(First reading the lower byte would require the min() function then.)
This requires the edge condition, that the turnaround-time of the timer is bigger than the execution time of the code above!

Comment: Normally you would hold the timer temporarily while taking the reading so that it won't update in between low and high reads.

Comment: Good point in stopping the timer.

Comment: Often you don't want to stop the timer, for example if it is used as a clock.

Comment: @starblue: Right. It is even intended to be a clock here. I was thinking about adding that lost amount of time before restarting. This is of course only possible if the CPU runs on a multiple of the timer's frequency. An the number of Opcodes executed while the timer is stopped must be fixed and known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would check to see if the counter value latches when the high or low byte is read. Many timers do.

Your second approach (to read the counter twice) is promising, but if possible remove any calculation between the first and second read of the timer and do all calculation afterwards. Also you need to check whether high byte wraparound (from 255 to 0) may also be an issue.

It would be helpful if in your question you stated what 8 bit controller and timer you were using, as people can give more specific advice by checking the datasheets and manuals

Comment: As already stated in the title, there is/may be no latch. And thanks for pointing out the wrap-around problem. I want to create a sample driver for a university course where the timers are written by students (Latch or not is their choice). This should be some kind of (bulletproof) sample routine. As I will provide it to the students, I dont want to tell them too much rubbish ;)

Comment: Many manufacturers seem to recommend "Sample as long as it takes to not hit an overflow", which I call [read twice and compare](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/Threading_and_Synchronization#read_twice_and_compare).

Answer (score 2):

You could unroll your first approach for two iterations, so you get

```
__DI();
upper1 = CounterH;
lower1 = CounterL;
upper2 = CounterH;
lower2 = CounterL;
__EI();
if ( upper1 == upper2 )
{
    // use lower1, upper1
}
else
{
    // use lower2, upper2
}
```

Here you assume that if `CounterL` overflowed between reading `upper1` and `upper2` it doesn't overflow again between reading `upper2` and `lower2`.

Since interrupts are disabled around the block of assignments it should always be fast enough, even for an 8-bit counter.